# Xamarin - IOS - Battery usage

Tags: ios, xamarin, gps, core-location, battery

I have developed an IOS application with Xamarin and am trying to find out what is consuming most significantly the battery. The application has three main activities:

1. Listen to location updates in the background (with AccurityNearestTenMeters and DistanceFilter = 50)
2. Write all the acquired locations every 10 seconds in a file
3. Send the file content to a remote server by using a standard HttpClient object

The application is consuming about 50% of the battery after 7 hours or so. It depends on the user movement but let's say that there are plenty of movements by walk, tramway, etc...then a reasonable amount of time where there is much less movements (i.e at work).

I have tried to change the desired accuracy to nearest 100 meter and also change the distance filter. I got some pretty good optimization especially for the accuracy change but I need to have more precise locations so am looking for another possibility if any to optimize the battery.

There are many questions that cross my mind and for which I would like to have your feedbacks please: what is more battery consuming?

Location updates or file writing? also the same for a network request so if I put it side by side what does consume more the battery: location updates, file writing or network requests. I mean from a general point of view.

Also, do you guys have any recommendations or information that can help me in this optimization?

Comment: You can use Instruments to log power usage while disconnected from your Mac and then upload the log for analysis, but I can tell you that it is the GPS receiver that is consuming your battery.  The distance filter won't really help you. Dialling down accuracy so that the GPS receiver is not used will help.

Comment: You could potentially turn off location updates when there is no movement for some period and use significant location change monitoring to give you a notification that the user has moved and you should start location updates again. This will give a bit of gap between when the user moves and your first location update, but it will reduce battery consumption.

Comment: Yes this looks good to test. Is there a standard way to check that there is no movement for a given period of time?

Comment: I managed to find an answer to my last question. I will try to do it the way you described and will let you know. Thanks for your help